# Double formatter to append trailing 0

Tags: java, format, double, decimalformat

I am using `DecimalFormat` class to format the `double` input to required format.

`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000000");`

Then, I am using `df.format(/*some value*/)`.

The problem is if I pass a double with more than 8 decimal part, it is formatting to 8 decimal part as required, but if I pass a value with less than 8 decimal part, it is not appending trailing `0`'s. How to achieve that?

`Example`

`df.format(12.67543456667)` will format it as `12.67543457`

But,

`df.format(12.675)` will format it to `12.675` only.

How to format it to `12.67500000` ?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant snippet of code?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, simply add:

```
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000000");` should works. Try to change symbols for the default FORMAT locale or pass `DecimalFormatSymbols` in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The same logic should work.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000000");
//System.out.println(df.format(12.67543456667));`
System.out.println(df.format(12.675));
```

output:-

```
12.67500000
```